# Identity Server 4 Client Api Syncing Registered Users

Tags: c#, .net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.0, openid-connect

Currently the first time a user logs in I use there token to register a new user with their subject Id.  I'm trying to register their username as well but I'm having trouble figuring out how, since there is no claim for their email.

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddIdentityServerAuthentication(o =>
    {
        o.Authority = "https://localhost:44366";
        o.ApiName = "Custom Api";
        o.JwtBearerEvents = new JwtBearerEvents
        {
            OnTokenValidated = async tokenValidationContext =>
            {
                var claimsIdentity = tokenValidationContext.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
                if (claimsIdentity == null)
                {
                    return;
                }

                string userId = claimsIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "sub").Value;

               //...
           }
       }
});
```

I noticed their email was included in the profile.  I would like to register the email address as their username. I don't want to take in the username seperately from the token because then the user could use their own token change their email in the api which I would like to disallow.

My Api resources:

```
    new ApiResource
    {
        Name = "myApi",
        DisplayName = "my API",
        Description = "my API Access",
        UserClaims = new List<string> {"role"},
        Scopes = new List<Scope>
        {
            new Scope("myApi.read"),
            new Scope("myApi.write")
        }
    }
```

And my Client Registration:

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "myClientJs",
    ClientName = "JavaScript Client",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
    AllowRememberConsent = true,
    //RequireConsent = true,
    AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,
    RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:8166/" },
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:8166/" },
    AllowedCorsOrigins = { "http://localhost:8166" },

    AllowedScopes =
    {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
        "myAPI",
    }
}
```

Client Configuration:

```
this.settings = {
    authority: environment.identityServerUrl,
    client_id: environment.clientAuthorityId,
    post_logout_redirect_uri: environment.logoutURI,
    redirect_uri: environment.redirectUri,
    response_type: "id_token token",
    scope: "openid profile email",
    automaticSilentRenew: true,
    filterProtocolClaims: true,
    loadUserInfo: true,
}
```

Is there a way I can sync my emails directly with identity server? If not is there a way I can include the email in the token claims directly, so it will be harder to tamper with?

However I would like the email to be included in the token is this possible?

Comment: you can do that by changing your clients, apiresources configs, please share them with us

Comment: @YahyaHussein Not too sure why you need these if its just a configuration option on there you could of just posted.  But I've editted to include the configuration and api Resources

Comment: Please share the code that you have for the JavaScript that defines how the client is configured to run. This will allow us to see if you have requested the 'Email' scope.

Comment: @aaronR Thanks, I think I'm missing the email scope I'll try that out when I get back

Comment: Incase anyone is wondering you can solve this by, loading their profile after the first time they login.  This pattern is commonly done with other OAuth logins, such as Facebook, so look at there code for examples